# trying to get feedback as email from a contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a created a html form and a php file (mail.php) and i have added this in my form `<form action="mail.php" method="POST">`

but  When I try to submit the form, instead of emailing me and providing the thank you message, it downloads the php page. When I run the .html page in my browser, it shows up fine but when I click send it downloads mail.php, instead of working.

Any suggestions?

ok this is the code

mail.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n telephone: $telephone \n  comments: $comments";
$recipient = "lllkk@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" ;
```

test.html:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="telephone"  class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" placeholder="Comments" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: Is your http://localhost working in browser ?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: ys localhost is working in browser

Comment: error is displayed as failed to connect to mail server

Comment: try adding a new file to localhost info.php with <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Above will display all settings of your local server and check if mail function is enabled (sendmail/postfix). If these settings are there plz check for mail.add_x_header is on.